# Trying to insert a string into a x position of another string

Tags: python

This what I have so far. It's for homework. We can't use slices. I can't seem to figure it out.

```
def insert(s1, s2, pos):
    s3 = list(s1)
    for i,s in enumerate(s3):
        if i == pos:
            s3[pos + 1] = s
            s3[i] = s2
    "".join(s3)     
    return s3
```

With the above, the last character of string `s1` gets deleted and the `join` method is not joining `s3` into a single string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice the lines

```
"".join(s3)     
return s3
```

If you look at [the join documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.join), you'll see that join doesn't modify its argument, but instead generates a string containing the contents of the argument list, all joined together.  So you're throwing away the result of

```
"".join(s3)
```

and returning `s3` (a list) instead.  So, you need to change the last two lines to

```
return ''.join(s3)
```

Since this is homework, I won't comment on the rest of the code, but returning the result of the join call will certainly help.

Comment: def insert(s1, s2, pos):
     s3 = list(s1)
     for i,s in enumerate(s3):
      if i == pos:
       s3.insert(i, s2)
    return ''.join(s3)

Thanks for the tip on join. It hit me I could use insert, but I'm not sure if my professor will allow it to be legal. Professor hates when we use built-in methods.

Comment: well, I think he's against using methods like `sort()` because one can write a really simple sorting algorithm in just 1 line in python using list comprehension AND some `if` statements inside. I am not sure how you would insert an element into your list without using insert or any other built-in methods in this case. Now if he doesn't allow insert, he must be insane because `insert` is a high-level API / method that people use to operate on `list`.

Comment: I think definition of a Python statement involves a `NEWLINE` termination.  You cannot have multiple statements without multiple `NEWLINE`'s.  What you're referring to is the "conditional expression."  Just some terminology :P  And the professor isn't crazy.  I imagine it's pretty standard to not use certain library functionalityies in languages until you understand what they do/an overview of how they do it.  Why else would you teach the implementation of various sorts, algorithms and data structures instead of just listing their various run-times?